# Cannot resolve symbol 'TitleProvider ' for ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, mobile

I'm taking over a old Android project that uses ViewPagerIndicator.  I've updated it to the latest version (2.4.1) but the import statement for com.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider is not resolving and there is some code I have that implements TitleProvider.  Any idea where the methods in TitleProvider got moved to?  I can't seem to find any documentation.

Comment: It's opensource and you can find changes https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/pull/70 and there is sample https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample

Answer (score 0):

They comment by @adrbtk lead me to the solution.  The only method I was overriding in TitleProvider was getTitle().  The support library's latest revision has a method called getPageTitle() so I got rid of the "implements TitleProvider" on the method and made the code change below.

Change this

```
    @Override
    public String getTitle(int index) {
        return ((MyFragment)getItem(index)).getTableName().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
```

to this

```
    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int index) {
        return ((MyFragment)getItem(index)).getTableName().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
```